# Ui-router AngularJS: How to access to session variable 'req.user'

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular to deal with some routes,on the server side I'm using passport so basically I can acess to the user session variable req.user in my views , but when it comes to a route renderred by ui-router my req.user is undefined. Any idea to access to the req.user even it's not an express route

app.js  code :

```
       // Express Session
       app.use(session({
        secret: 'secret',
        saveUninitialized: true,
         resave: true
        }));

        // Passport init
        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());

        // Global Vars
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
        res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
        res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
        res.locals.user = req.user || null;
        next();
        });
```

my passport code is as follows :

```
passport.use('employee',new LocalStrategy(
function(email, password, done) {

    Employee.getUserByEmail(email, function(errEmp, emp){

            if(errEmp ) throw errEmp;
            if(!emp){
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
            }
            if(emp) {
                Employee.comparePassword(password, emp.encryptedpass,  function (err, isMatch) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) {
                        return done(null, emp);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
                    }
                });
            }
    });
}
));


      router.get('/',ensureAuthenticated ,function(req, res, next) {

      res.render('index', { title: 'Nubes' });

       });


     function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){




    if(req.isAuthenticated()){

    Employee.findById(req.user.id,function (err,emp) {


        if(emp) {
            res.render('employee/index');
        }

    })
} 

    }



router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {

Employee.findOne({email:req.body.username},function (err,emp) {

    if(emp){
        passport.authenticate('employee', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                return res.redirect('/');
            });
        })(req, res, next);
     })
     });
```

In my rendered page 'employee/index' I can display my user information  but routes that  rendered by ui-router don't have a user variable

here is an example code of angular route :

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url:'/',
        templateUrl:'/views/employee/home.html'
    })
```

in home.html user is not defined which is normal because it's not express server who rendred it . what I want is to get this user variable in my ui-router rendered pages

Comment: Do you have any code to post? It would make it easier probably :)

Comment: Hi Olly , I've  posted  some code in my post

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to implement token based authentication using something like JWT-tokens, you have also passport plugins for those.

If you still want to use sessions based info and pass it to the client, you can store them in some global JS variable, which i highly dont recommend.

here some info about jwt: https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

for the locals if using handlebars it would look something like this:

```
 <script>
     var user = {{user}};
 </script>
```

just note that you might need to implement some JSON stringify and decoding in order to get the info as JS object.